# Como agrandar el tamaño y espesor de los símbolos de la leyenda en R

Tags: r

estoy haciendo un código en R. Y lo que me interesa hacer es agrandar el símbolo que esta marcando en celeste, quiero agrandarlo, para que se note.
Igual me gustaría saber como colocar en negrito los títulos y como se agregan los subíndices de una palabra.

Adjunto el código.

```
BM1 [1,1] <- 1.2
BM1 [2,1] <- 1.2
BM1 [1,2] <- 1
BM1 [2,2] <- 1
## PLOTEO FIGURA - BALANCE DE MASA

LWDD  <- 3
par(mfrow=c(1,1), pin=c(3,3))

plot(BM1[1,1],BM1[1,2],main="Balance de Masa en Cuenca XXXX",asp=1,type="p",cex=3,pch=23,xlab="Q/P [-]",ylab="ET/P [-]" ,
     ylim=c(0 , 2),xlim=c(0,2),las=1,col="black",bg="red",lwd=LWDD)

lines(BM1[2,1],BM1[2,2],pch=21,type="p",lwd=LWDD,cex=3,xlab="Q/P [-]",ylab="ET/P [-]" , las=1,col="black",bg="red",xaxt="n")

lines(c(-0.5,1.5),c(1.5,-0.5), col="black", lwd=2, lty=2)

legend(1.1,1.9,title="Modelo",font.main="bold",legend=c("GRJ4","GRJ4+CN"),cex = 1, col=c("black","black"),bg="azure", pch=c(23,21),pch.lwd=c(3,3))

legend(0.1,1.9,title="Cuenca",legend=c("Cuenca 1","Cuenca 2"),fill=c("red","green"),cex = 1, col=c("black","black"),bg="azure")
```

Comment: Hi, your answer help me a lot. But how could I delete the line in the symbols in "Modelo". And Another question, how to do, for example, GRJ[4] but incluying bold style, is it possible? I tried with your example, but it doesnt recognize the expression function. Do you know why? I just need to combine subscript + bold style, do you knwo how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy apprendiendo español, pero creo que entender tu pregunta. No soy un experto pero tengo la habilidad a encontrar las repuestas en inglés. Espero que los te ayuda.

1. Para agrandar los símbolos: usa `pt.cex`  [fuente en inglés](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-February/425395.html)
2. Para colocar en negrito los títulos: usa `as.expression(bquote(bold("texto")))` [fuente en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177810/r-make-the-text-bold-for-the-legend-and-the-xlab-ylab-parameters-in-a-plot)
3. Para agregarse los subíndices : usa `expression('texto'[subíndice]`); usa una `*` para obtener un espacio. [fuente en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156417/subscripts-in-plots-in-r)

```
BM1 <- matrix(rep(0,4), nrow=2, ncol=2)

BM1 [1,1] <- 1.1
BM1 [2,1] <- 1.3
BM1 [1,2] <- 0.9
BM1 [2,2] <- 1
## PLOTEO FIGURA - BALANCE DE MASA

LWDD  <- 3
par(mfrow=c(1,1), pin=c(3,3))

plot(BM1[1,1],BM1[1,2],main="Balance de Masa en Cuenca XXXX",asp=1,type="p",cex=3,pch=23,xlab="Q/P [-]",ylab="ET/P [-]" ,
     ylim=c(0 , 2),xlim=c(0,2),las=1,col="black",bg="red",lwd=LWDD)

lines(BM1[2,1],BM1[2,2],pch=21,type="p",lwd=LWDD,cex=3,xlab="Q/P [-]",ylab="ET/P [-]" , las=1,col="black",bg="green",xaxt="n")

lines(c(-0.5,1.5),c(1.5,-0.5), col="black", lwd=2, lty=2)

legend(1.1,1.9,title=as.expression(bquote(bold("Modelo"))),legend=c(expression('GRJ'[4]), expression('GRJ'[4]*"+CN")), cex = 1, col=c("black","black"),bg="azure", pch=c(23,21), pt.cex=c(2,2), lwd=c(3,3))

legend(0.1,1.9,title=as.expression(bquote(bold("Cuenca"))),legend=c("Cuenca 1","Cuenca 2"),fill=c("red","green"),cex = 1, col=c("black","black"),bg="azure")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I'm not an expert on this, but using the `as.expression(bquote(bold('GRJ'[4])))` seems to work to achieve the bold and subscript. add `pt.bg = 'azure'` to set the background of pch so the line doesn't show through.

```
legend(1.1,1.9,title=as.expression(bquote(bold("Modelo"))),legend=c(as.expression(bquote(bold('GRJ'[4]))), as.expression(bquote(bold('GRJ'[4]*"+CN")))), cex = 1, col=c("black","black"),bg="azure", pch=c(23,21), pt.cex=c(2,2),  pt.bg = 'azure', lwd = c(3,3))
```

`expression` is a base function so I'm unclear on why it doesn't work on your computer. I am running the following when I enter `sessionInfo()` into the Console:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]